# Log4Net.Error throws VerificationException - Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: log4net

We are running into this issue when we log errors/fatal message using log4net.

> System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the
>   runtime.    at log4net.Core.LogImpl.Fatal(Object message, Exception
>   exception)

Strangely this happens only when we log as Error/Fatal, Info and Debug messages log perfectly fine. Because of this exception, the real exceptions are getting masked and its making it very hard for us to debug in deployed environments.

I have tried searching online but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Environment details:

```
IIS 7.5 / Win 2008 R2
.Net 4.0
MVC3 and WCF applications
```

Here is the logging configuration-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,   log4net"/>
      </configSections>  
      <log4net>
      <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\Logs\ApplicationServices.log" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">      
          <conversionPattern value="${COMPUTERNAME} %date %-5level %class.%method - %message%newline"/>
        </layout>
      </appender>
      <root>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
      </root>
    </log4net>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you give us one example logging call that throws? Is this logging-call done in a catch that was caused by System.Security.VerificationException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime. This exception will be thrown if the .Net Security system identifies the code as not type safe.

If you run peverify.exe against the log4net.dll version 1.2.11(latest version at this time), you will get the below error.

```
log4net.Plugin.RemoteLoggingServerPlugin::Attach][offset 0x0000002C] Method is not visible.
1 Error(s) Verifying log4net.dll.
```

You can find more details on how to make the log4net code to pass the verification in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297419/log4net-doesnt-pass-verification-when-compiling).